# Inversion Of Control - Large Scale Example

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

I understand inversion of control and the concepts behind it. It all makes sense, however my knowledge comes from articles and books that only provide over simplistic models and scenarios.

In my case, I have no one at work with solid experience in an architecture of this kind, so I have no way to validate my design. Are there any good examples of systems where IoC is done right?

Moreover, in my case I tend to declare interfaces and models in separate assemblies that get imported by both the invokers and the implementer (injecting dependencies at boot). However, this leads to a lot of projects, and I sometimes find hard to justify having assemblies implementing only two or three classes, just for the sake of decoupling. I keep wondering that maybe you can achieve a similar level of isolation with just namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

IoC does not in any way require you to have many assemblies - you can have one or as many as you feel necessary/required for versioning or other external reasons.

There are good arguments for all options including both extremes (several classes per assembly to one assembly for all) and you'd need to pick your one.

Things to consider:

- can build + unit tests for piece of code you are working on finish quickly (i.e. under 1 minute) - if not consider making smaller assemblies and separate projects more carefully
- do you provide external APIs - if yes consider splitting "stable interface" set of assemblies and "often changing implementation/details" assemblies.
- does your team require physical separation of code between assemblies to avoid tight coupling of objects or just convention is enough (less projects may be easier to manage)
- how tools you are using impacted by number/size of projects